# Sumo Logic metric query override quantize rollup but leave default interval?

Tags: sumologic

Can I override the `quantize` rollup (default `avg`) without overriding the interval?  That way I can change the quantize rollup to say `max` but still have the dynamic interval inherited from the dashboard it's in.

E.g. `quantize to inherited using max`

**Use Case**

A category has 5 hosts.  I want to know the max memory usage any host had during a quantized interval.  And then I want the max of all hosts.  So I might make a query like:

```
_sourceCategory=x metric=process.memory.usage process.executable.name=my-bin 
| quantize to 5m using max 
| max
```

But I want it to work in a dashboard so that the `5m` is dynamic and not hard-coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `quantize using max` to achieve this. This way you will use the `max` rollup, but with the default quantization granularity.

Using the query from your example, it should look like this:

```
_sourceCategory=x metric=process.memory.usage process.executable.name=my-bin 
| quantize using max 
| max
```